# Get average balances from transactions?

Tags: dataset, inference

I don't know if this forum or the DS forum is better but I'll start here.

I have a project that has been presented to me but I'm trying to think of the tools that I would apply to this (or if it's even possible). I have obscured the exact details in order to protect the project, but here is a good illustration:

Let's say there is a bank and you want to find the average account balance of all the people that have an account with that bank. You only have information on transactions and nothing else to go on. So you have information like:

- Three hundred bank members each just wrote a check for \$125
- Two hundred bank members just bought coffee at $2.50 each
- 400 members just had deposits of various values each
- I do not know how many members the bank has at any given time
- I do not have any information on the current balances (i.e. starting balances) of any bank members

Is this enough information to draw an inference on the average account balance of each member? I can track members both individually and in the aggregate but the datasets may not always be complete; I might miss individual transactions and never know it.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not enough information to know the average account balance of each member.

Consider trying to determine the average account balance over the past year of a customer who has a single transaction, which was a \$100 deposit 6 months ago. If their initial balance was \$0, then their average account balance over the past year was \$50. If their initial balance was \$100, then their average account balance over the past year was \$150.

If you don't know the initial balance, you can't really hope to accurately estimate the average balance from transactional data. The best you can do is to lower bound it (in our simple example, they can't have started this year with a negative balance, so their balance for the year was no less than \$50).